# assign an animated image to contacts

Tags: contacts

Is it possible to assign an animated image to contacts in my address book?

So when a person from my contacts calls me it would play an animated image instead of a static image.

I have tried using animated GIFs, but it doesn't seem to work. I was wondering if there is a work-around. Preferably without having to root my phone.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It simply doesn't seem possible. On Android, pictures are shown in ImageView components, and this component does not support displaying gifs. On most Android versions, you can't do it. Maybe a custom Contacts app can have the capability.